# Glyphicons from bootstrap doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="sidebar left">
    <div id="app-navigation" class="well">
      <h5>Administration</h5>
      <ul class="administration-list">
        <li class="user"><a href="#user">User</a></li>
        <li class="emails"><a href="#emails">Emails</a></li>
        <li class="settings"><a href="#Settings">Settings</a></li>
        <li class="logs"><a href="#Logs">Logs</a></li>
        <li class="help"><a href="#Help">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <h5>Managing tools</h5>
      <ul class="tools-list">
        <li class="ressource"><a href="#Ressources"><i class="icon-home icon-white" </i>Ressources</a></li>
        <li class="playlist"><a href="#Playlist">Playlist</a></li>
        <li class="schedule"><a href="#Schedule">Schedule</a></li>
        <li class="stations"><a href="#Stations">Stations</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why my icon doesn't show up. I'm starting a new project and decided to try out  [initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) with [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). Just can't make those icon appear. It's seems there's an invisible icon just before my text... I have check the documentation too, [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html). I also checked within my boostrap.less, sprites.less and variables.less (everything seems okay...).

My variable are correctly set and my image (PNG) are in my ../img folder.

```
// Sprite icons path
// -------------------------
@iconSpritePath:          "../img/glyphicons-halflings.png";
@iconWhiteSpritePath:     "../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

Comment: Check your assets folder to see if your icons image is there.

Comment: Did u try to change '../img/' to just '/img/'? It looks like your img folder isn't paired up with the css folder.

Comment: Yes. I did that too.. But I think I found the answer... thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The file variables.less is at the bootstrap folder, so you need one more level to get to root.

Try to set the path to:

```
@iconSpritePath:          "../../img/glyphicons-halflings.png";
@iconWhiteSpritePath:     "../../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

Comment: I don't understand why they didn't put it / or set the correct value with their infrastructure...

Comment: Just as an update to this, the variable as of bootstrap 3 is called `@icon-font-path` and is defaulted to `"../fonts/"`

Answer (score 5):

In the newest Bootstrap icons are included with the new class glyphicon:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
```

In some cases that will probably be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy the img folder from bootstrap in the less folder... or you could change the variable to point to root/img folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open the rewrites.php file in the 'lib' folder. Add the following line within the function **'roots_add_rewrites($content)'**:

```
    'assets/fonts/(.*)'    => THEME_PATH . '/assets/fonts/$1',
```

The function should look like this:

```
function roots_add_rewrites($content) {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $roots_new_non_wp_rules = array(
    'assets/css/(.*)'      => THEME_PATH . '/assets/css/$1',
    'assets/js/(.*)'       => THEME_PATH . '/assets/js/$1',
    'assets/img/(.*)'      => THEME_PATH . '/assets/img/$1',
    'assets/fonts/(.*)'    => THEME_PATH . '/assets/fonts/$1',
    'plugins/(.*)'         => RELATIVE_PLUGIN_PATH . '/$1'
  );
  $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules = array_merge($wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules, $roots_new_non_wp_rules);
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: Nice, perhaps, for PHP users, but was there any indication that this question had anything to do with PHP?