# Bootstrap Icons have stopped appearing my app

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

***UPDATE***: I fixed this problem. The problem was that in my settings file I was pointing it to download the CSS from Amazon S3 versus my local machine. On S3 I did not have the files set properly with permissions. As a result, it was not working.

For some reason the icons are no longer appearing in my app ever since pointing my static files to S3.

I have the following code:

`<i class="icon-globe"></i>`

However, nothing is showing up. This was working previously, so not sure why it is no longer displaying.

In the page source, it doesn't show a path to the image, just this:

```
<h5><i class="icon-globe"></i> New York </h5>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
[class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  *margin-right: .3em;
  *margin-right: .3em;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url("../../../images/icons/glyphicons-halflings.png");
  background-position: 14px 14px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
[class^="icon-"]:last-child,
[class*=" icon-"]:last-child {
  *margin-left: 0;
}
[class^="icon-"]:last-child,
[class*=" icon-"]:last-child {
  *margin-left: 0;
}
.icon-white {
  background-image: url("../../../images/icons/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
}
.icon-globe {
  background-position: 0      0;
}
```

Do I need to set a path for each icon I'm using? I didn't have to do this before on my local machine, but saw the icons, so not sure if that's necessary or not.

Note: before background-image was hardcoded to my static directory which is why the problem arose -- I think.

Comment: what have you change in recent past? Show with code so that we can help

Comment: If you check your favorite developer tools (Firebug, etc.), does it report a 404 error for the sprite?

Comment: Have you checked that the icon actually exists? (icon name)

Comment: Hey @ViralShah that's a good point. Where are the image files stored and how does Bootstrap learn their location?

Comment: The icons are in the `img` directory. There should be two files: `glyphicons-halflings.png` and `glyphicons-halflings-white.png`. Did you upload those?

Answer (score 0):

There probably is an issue finding the images.

Find the definition of the `icon-globe` class. And reconcile it with the actual location of your images file.

Answer (score 0):

*This was working previously* - locally or on some remote web server..??

In case it was working locally and not on the remote server then you need to upload *img* directory which include glyphicons files..mentioning this because i made this mistake once..

Additionally, [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460713/glyphicons-from-bootstrap-doesnt-show-up), if it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the s3 access permissions for the file using the aws console? Depending on how you uploaded them, they could be locked for public access (ie via a web browser)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change different url, I mean to say try with www or without www and open the site. If it open well without www. its means your icons css stylesheet path is not set according to the www. I have made this mistake once.